# Multi column list box in forms 11g

Tags: oracleforms

Please have a look at attached file and advise if similar features are available in oracle Form 11g. I tried everything in oracle form 11g but fail to work out. Is it possible to use similar windows features to achieve the same result and how? Many thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0UD5.gif)

Comment: What do you mean with similar features? You can use tabs, scroll window, design block to look "similar" to your table. You can design pagination like in your picture, but you don't need it, you simply and quick browse records using keyboard.

Comment: Please forget the other part of the form only concentrate on list box not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Multi column list box is not possible, you can only concatenate your data to show it as one column.

In forms there exists `LOV` for this type of data.

So I suggest you use this.

If this is not ok for you the only option you got is to use Java pluggable components ( java bean ) to make it yourself.